# Saving the lastest state of an entire application in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an interactive web based visualization. I want to allow users to be able to undo while interacting with the visualization. I noticed some people suggest writing my own undo function but in my case it might be really difficult (so many different things to keep track of). How can I save the last state of the entire application after each interaction?  Any idea?

Thanks,

Comment: Where you keep your state? Show us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a more state-driven approach and use something like React + Redux, but it sounds like you already have an existing app that you don't want to recreate.

In this case, it really depends on what your data looks like. Is it a single JSON object? In that case, you could clone the object over and over which would "save" the previous states.

You could implement a database and save a copy of all the needed data with timestamps and/or version numbers to allow you to roll back. This will obviously lead to a LOT of duplication of data.

Another approach would be to keep track of all the events that modify your data, and then do the opposite of that event. As a very basic example, I add the number 15 to my "total". If I wanted to undo that, I would subtract 15. However, this only works if you are performing operations on all of your data. If you want to apply this to different types of data, you could store the event along with the previous value.

Example: I change my name from "Bob" to "Jim". The event could be an object:

```
{
  event: "stringChange",
  prop: "name",
  prev: "Bob",
  new: "Jim"
}
```

This would give you everything you need to undo your change.

Lots of options here, it just really depends on what your data looks like and how you are manipulating it.